# SQL Synced Columns Across a Row

Tags: sql, sql-update, synchronization

I swear I remember learning how to do this, but I can't remember the keyword to find it, basically, I want to have a column on my table that automatically updates when another column, on the same table, is modified. I want the updating to basically be a value obtained through a short SQL script, based on other values in the same table.

The biggest problem is making it automatically update upon modifications to the columns it's value is obtained from, similar to how an Excel Spreadsheet would update.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **[COMPUTED COLUMN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)** first, and then a trigger if a computed column can't do it.    Like the Age column in this example.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    FirstName       VARCHAR(20),
    LastName        VARCHAR(20),
    DateOfBirth     DATETIME,
    Age         AS Cast(DateDiff("mm", DateOfBirth, GetDate())/12 AS INTEGER)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the "trigger" keyword?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html
It basically does what you described

Comment: He beat you to it, but yes, that's exactly what I was trying to find, thanks for the tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate using a [Database Trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) to accomplish this. Different RDBMSes have different ways of creating them, so check your RDBMS documentation.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's exactly the keyword I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of a self-referencing [foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a database trigger.

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Sql Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx

(hopefully that gets you started, anyway!  :) )

Essentially, you'll create a trigger for INSERT and UPDATE, to make sure the value is kept the same.